# dynamic program "all_construct" (or "word break") problem

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to implement [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&t=10180s) (from 3.06 to 3.08 if link doesn't point to appropriated time stamp) approach for the problem.

```cpp
using words_t = std::vector<std::string>;
using result_t = std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>;
using memo_t = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>;


result_t
all_construct_impl(const std::string &target,
                   const words_t &words,
                   memo_t &memo) {
    if (memo.count(target)) return memo[target];
    if (target.empty()) return result_t(0, std::vector<std::string>(0, ""));

    result_t result;
    const auto beg = target.cbegin();

    for (const auto &word : words) {
        const auto word_size = static_cast<long long int>(word.size());
        const std::string starts_with(beg, beg + word_size);

        if (starts_with == word) {
            const std::string suffix(beg + word_size, target.cend());
            auto suffix_ways = all_construct_impl(suffix, words, memo);
            if (suffix_ways.empty()) { // maybe here?
                suffix_ways.emplace_back(std::vector<std::string>(1, word));
            } else {
                for_each(suffix_ways.begin(), suffix_ways.end(), [&word](auto &way) { way.insert(way.cbegin(), word); });
            }
            for_each(suffix_ways.cbegin(), suffix_ways.cend(), [&result](const auto &way) { result.push_back(way); });
        }
    }

    memo[target] = result;
    return result;
}


result_t
all_construct(const std::string& target, const words_t& words)
{
    memo_t memo{};
    return all_construct_impl(target, words, memo);
}
```

This works well for the following inputs:

```
std::string("foobar"), std::vector<std::string>{"f", "oo", "bar"}
std::string("foobar"), std::vector<std::string>{"foo", "b", "ar", "bar"}
// outputs:
[
 [f oo bar ],
]
[
 [foo b ar ],
 [foo bar ],
]
```

But fail for this one:

```
std::string("eeeeeef"), std::vector<std::string>{"eee", "eeee"}
// output not empty vector:
[
 [eee eee ],
 [eeee ],
]
```

It seems to me that `suffix_ways.empty()` is a root of my problem, but without this instruction empty array is returned.

Comment: Please describe what "_this approach_" is in short so that we don't need to watch the whole youtube video to get a clue.

Comment: Also, please explain what "fails" mean. Does it crash? Do you get the wrong output?

Comment: update my question :)

Comment: @UlrichVonRekkenin Please put the relevant information in the question. Describe what it is that you want to achieve - in textual form. It'd also help if you provided a [mre].